# Calling functions in Web Workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Ok this is kinda difficult to explain  but here goes, I am using web workers and I have functions defined in my web workers script, and I would like to call a particular function passing in another function as arguments, the problem is I am trying to do this from my main script using worker.postMessage. It might be clearer if I post some code...

This is from my main script:

```
worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'register', 'funcName': 'someFunction'});
```

This is from the worker script:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;

switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'register':
        registerEvent(data.funcName);
        break;
    case 'unregister':
        break;
    default:
        self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
    };
}, false);

function someFunction() {

}

function registerEvent(someFunction) {

}
```

So I know this code is wrong and won't work, but I guess you have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;

    switch (data.cmd) {
        case 'register':
            registerEvent(data.funcName);
            break;
        case 'unregister':
            break;
        default:
            self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
    };
}, false);

self.someFunction = function() {}

function registerEvent(someFunctionName) {
    self[someFunctionName]();
}
```

or create a separate object with the function, but make sure it is a method of an object, then it becomes easy to call like that.

Comment: Great thanks for that, If I had 20 odd functions would it get verbose using a single object with 20 methods?

Comment: I don't thinks so. It's acting more like an indexed dictionary than anything else. And you could always look at using [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries) if you're worried about it getting cluttered.

Comment: where should i write this function in service worker or in js file attached in page?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to look at the [vkTread](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/) plugin. This plugin allows you to execute any function of your code in a thread.

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/

Best regards,

--Vadim

Comment: I suggest this is the best way to do it. +1 for you vadimk